# Splitting a string with using a custom delimiter in c++ using cin

Tags: c++, string, split, cin

I need to take in the following string and split it into two strings: one before the hyphen, and one after the hyphen. I then need to change the data type to an int. However I need to use `cin`.

Here is the string: `1-6`

I tried using other methods, although my lecturer said I'm not allowed to.

Comment: Did you try splitting the string using `cin`, by providing a custom delimiter?

Comment: `int a,c; char b; cin >> a >> b >> c;`

Answer (score 1):

> split it into two strings one before the hyphen

```
std::string before;
std::getline(std::cin, before, '-');
```

> and one after the hyphen

```
std::string after;
std::getline(std::cin, after);
```

> I then need to change the data type to an int.

```
const int b = std::stoi(before);
const int a = std::stoi(after);
```